# Regex Replacing &#58; to ":" etc

Tags: c++, regex, boost, ascii, ncr

I've got a bunch of strings like:

```
"Hello, here's a test colon&#58;. Here's a test semi-colon&#59;"
```

I would like to replace that with

```
"Hello, here's a test colon:. Here's a test semi-colon;"
```

And so on for all [printable ASCII values](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_ascii.asp).

At present I'm using [`boost::regex_search`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_search.html) to match `&#(\d+);`, building up a string as I process each match in turn (including appending the substring containing no matches since the last match I found).

Can anyone think of a better way of doing it? I'm open to non-regex methods, but regex seemed a reasonably sensible approach in this case.

Thanks,

Dom

Comment: Number in entities is NOT ASCII. It's Unicode codepoint number and it can be outside 0-255 range.

Comment: ... in which case we presumably can leave it untouched.
(BTW, printable ASCII range is 32-126)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there's already a library out there (possibly even as part of boost) to convert XML entities to their utf-8/utf-16 equivalents.

Comment: If there is it's good to know that the formal name of those entities is Numeric character reference (NCR). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference – PEZ

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The big advantage of using a regex is to deal with the tricky cases like `&#38;#38;` Entity replacement isn't iterative, it's a single step. The regex is also going to be fairly efficient: the two lead characters are fixed, so it will quickly skip anything not starting with `&#`. Finally, the regex solution is one without a lot of surprises for future maintainers.

I'd say a regex was the right choice.

Is it the best regex, though? You know you need two digits and if you have 3 digits, the first one will be a 1. Printable ASCII is after all `&#32;-&#126;`. For that reason, you could consider `&#1?\d\d;`.

As for replacing the content, I'd use the [basic algorithm described for boost::regex::replace](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_replace.html) :

```
For each match // Using regex_iterator<>
    Print the prefix of the match
    Remove the first 2 and last character of the match (&#;)
    lexical_cast the result to int, then truncate to char and append.

Print the suffix of the last match.
```

Comment: Good suggestion on the &#1?\d\d - thanks (and +1). Can you think of a way of doing the replace with a regex as well?

Comment: Thanks - the algorithm you've given is roughly what I did (though I used &#(1?\d\d); to allow me access to the numeric value without stripping off characters). Running the resulting algorithm 100,000 times over a 320 character string with 20 values to replace takes 10 seconds. Nice!

Comment: Oh - if speed matters, abuse the fact that you've already validated your input. The result is then ((match[5]==';') ? (match[3]*10+match[4]) : (100+match[4]*10+match[5])) -'0'*11

Answer (score 3):

This will probably earn me some down votes, seeing as this is not a c++, boost or regex response, but here's a SNOBOL solution. This one works for ASCII. Am working on something for Unicode.

```
        NUMS = '1234567890'
MAIN    LINE = INPUT                                :F(END)
SWAP    LINE ?  '&#' SPAN(NUMS) . N ';' = CHAR( N ) :S(SWAP)
        OUTPUT = LINE                               :(MAIN)
END
```

Comment: I'm impressed. Can't make sense of that code at all and must now check SNOBOL up. +1

Comment: This is not correct.  It will decode "&#38;#65;" to "A" instead of "&#65;"

Comment: @Glomek is right, I think the right code may be 

SWAP    LINE ?  REM '&#' SPAN(NUMS) . N ';' = CHAR( N ) :S(SWAP)

Comment: That doesn't change the input string at all.

Answer (score 3):

```
* Repaired SNOBOL4 Solution
* &#38;#38; -> &#38;
     digit = '0123456789'
main line = input                        :f(end)
     result = 
swap line arb . l
+    '&#' span(digit) . n ';' rem . line :f(out)
     result = result l char(n)           :(swap)
out  output = result line                :(main)
end
```

Comment: "& &#65;" => " A" instead of "& A"

Comment: I was trying to make it more efficient -- obviously didn't work: try "arb" instead of "break('&')"

Comment: I put the change into your post.  So far I have not found an input that breaks this version.

Comment: +1 -- I'm totally impressed that there are still SNOBOL programmers around -- I love that language, but haven't used it in >30 years.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the regex support in boost, but check if it has a replace() method that supports callbacks or lambdas or some such. That's the usual way to do this with regexes in other languages I'd say.

Here's a Python implementation:

```
s = "Hello, here's a test colon&#58;. Here's a test semi-colon&#59;"
re.sub(r'&#(1?\d\d);', lambda match: chr(int(match.group(1))), s)
```

Producing:

```
"Hello, here's a test colon:. Here's a test semi-colon;"
```

I've looked some at boost now and I see it has a regex_replace function. But C++ really confuses me so I can't figure out if you could use a callback for the replace part. But the string matched by the (\d\d) group should be available in $1 if I read the boost docs correctly. I'd check it out if I were using boost.

Comment: I've added '1?' to the regexp.

Comment: The `lamdba ..` is wrong. It replaces non-printable ASCII characters e.g., '&#07'. Note: `c` is ASCII-printable iff 31 < ord(c) < 127 (for the sake of html documents).

Comment: Yeah, it's mainly meant as an example of the approach.

Comment: To fix the code without touching the lambda you could use a more restrictive regex e.g., r'&#(3[2-9]|[4-9]\d|1(?:[01]\d|2[0-6]));' See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428013/regex-replacing-58-to-etc#433565

Answer (score 1):

The existing SNOBOL solutions don't handle the multiple-patterns case properly, due to there only being one "&".  The following solution ought to work better:

```
        dd = "0123456789"
        ccp = "#" span(dd) $ n ";" *?(s = s char(n)) fence (*ccp | null)
   rdl  line = input                              :f(done)
   repl line "&" *?(s = ) ccp = s                 :s(repl)
        output = line                             :(rdl)
   done
   end
```

Comment: the single quote after the # should be a double-quote. sorry.

Comment: This converts "&#38;#38;" into "&&" and not "&#38;" as it should.  It also converts "&#65&#59;" to "A" and not "&#65;" as it should, and it doesn't work on codes at the end of the line unless &fullscan is turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Ya know, as long as we're off topic here, perl substitution has an 'e' option.  As in *evaluate expression*. E.g.

> echo "Hello, here's a test colon&#58;. Here's a test semi-colon&#59;
>   Further test &#38;#65;. abc.&#126;.def." 
> | perl -we 'sub translate { my $x=$_[0]; if ( ($x >= 32) && ($x <= 126) ) 
> { return sprintf("%c",$x); } else { return "&#".$x.";"; } } 
> while (<>) { s/&#(1?\d\d);/&translate($1)/ge; print; }'

Pretty-printing that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

sub translate
{
  my $x=$_[0];

  if ( ($x >= 32) && ($x <= 126) )
  {
    return sprintf( "%c", $x );
  }
  else
  {
    return "&#" . $x . ";" ;
  }
}

while (<>)
{
  s/&#(1?\d\d);/&translate($1)/ge;
  print;
}
```

Though perl being perl, I'm sure there's a much better way to write that...

---

Back to C code:

You could also roll your own finite state machine.  But that gets messy and troublesome to maintain later on.

Comment: @mrree: I've posted another perl one-liner http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428013/regex-replacing-58-to-etc#431247

Comment: JF:  Umm, thanks.  I wondered why the perl code no longer ran.  I t hought I must have been sleep-coding when I used single-quotes instead of double-quotes in that echo.  (It's fixed now.)

Comment: To show examples correctly replace `&#` by `&amp;#` in the markup. btw, single quotes work with `echo` just fine.

Comment: "&amp;": I didn't realize SO wasn't translating "&" correctly. I did add a number of '\\' chars to avoid SO misinterpreting other characters. Single/Double quotes have different effects on TCSH/BASH. In this particular case, there are single quotes in the text. echo 'here's a' vs echo "here's a".

Answer (score 1):

Here's another Perl's one-liner (see [@mrree's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428013/regex-replacing-58-to-etc#430191)):

- a test file:

```
$ cat ent.txt 
Hello, &#12; here's a test colon&#58;. 
Here's a test semi-colon&#59; '&#131;'
```

- the one-liner:

```
$ perl -pe's~&#(1?\d\d);~
> sub{ return chr($1) if (31 < $1 && $1 < 127); $& }->()~eg' ent.txt
```

- or using more specific regex:

```
$ perl -pe"s~&#(1(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-6])|3[2-9]|[4-9][0-9]);~chr($1)~eg" ent.txt
```

- both one-liners produce the same output:

```
Hello, &#12; here's a test colon:. 
Here's a test semi-colon; '&#131;'
```

Comment: Very clever!   I'm impressed!   Once piece of advice:  You might want to use '|' rather than '!' as the s// separator character if you plan to run this on the command-line in CSH/TCSH.  (! is special even inside single-quotes.)

Comment: @mrree: I've replaced '!' by '~'.

Answer (score 1):

[boost::spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/spirit/classic/doc/introduction.html) parser generator framework allows easily to create a parser that transforms desirable [NCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference)s.

```
// spirit_ncr2a.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_core.hpp>

int main() {
  using namespace BOOST_SPIRIT_CLASSIC_NS; 

  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    assert(parse(line.begin(), line.end(),
         // match "&#(\d+);" where 32 <= $1 <= 126 or any char
         *(("&#" >> limit_d(32u, 126u)[uint_p][&putchar] >> ';')
           | anychar_p[&putchar])).full); 
    putchar('\n');
  }
}
```

- compile:

```
    $ g++ -I/path/to/boost -o spirit_ncr2a spirit_ncr2a.cpp
```

- run:

```
    $ echo "Hello, &#12; here's a test colon&#58;." | spirit_ncr2a
```

- output:

```
    "Hello, &#12; here's a test colon:."
```

Answer (score 0):

I did think I was pretty good at regex but I have never seen lambdas been used in regex, please enlighten me!

I'm currently using python and would have solved it with this oneliner:

```
''.join([x.isdigit() and chr(int(x)) or x for x in re.split('&#(\d+);',THESTRING)])
```

Does that make any sense?

Comment: If you're going for pithiness, (pythyness?), you can take out the [] brackets.  FYI.

Comment: I added a Python example to my answer in case you're still curious. Instead of the lambda you could call a named/regular function.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but I think it's clearer to do a re.sub().

Answer (score 0):

Here's a NCR scanner created using [Flex](http://www.gnu.org/software/flex/):

```
/** ncr2a.y: Replace all NCRs by corresponding printable ASCII characters. */
%%
&#(1([01][0-9]|2[0-6])|3[2-9]|[4-9][0-9]); { /* accept 32..126 */
  /**recursive: unput(atoi(yytext + 2)); skip '&#'; `atoi()` ignores ';' */
  fputc(atoi(yytext + 2), yyout); /* non-recursive version */
}
```

To make an executable:

```
$ flex ncr2a.y
$ gcc -o ncr2a lex.yy.c -lfl
```

Example:

```
$ echo "Hello, &#12; here's a test colon&#58;. 
> Here's a test semi-colon&#59; '&#131;'
> &#38;#59; <-- may be recursive" \
> | ncr2a
```

It prints for non-recursive version:

```
Hello, &#12; here's a test colon:.
Here's a test semi-colon; '&#131;'
&#59; <-- may be recursive
```

And the recursive one produces:

```
Hello, &#12; here's a test colon:.
Here's a test semi-colon; '&#131;'
; <-- may be recursive
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those cases where the original problem statement apparently isn't very complete, it seems, but if you really want to only trigger on cases which produce characters between 32 and 126, that's a trivial change to the solution I posted earlier.  Note that my solution also handles the multiple-patterns case (although this first version wouldn't handle cases where some of the adjacent patterns are in-range and others are not).

```
      dd = "0123456789"
      ccp = "#" span(dd) $ n *lt(n,127) *ge(n,32) ";" *?(s = s char(n))
 +      fence (*ccp | null)
 rdl  line = input                              :f(done)
 repl line "&" *?(s = ) ccp = s                 :s(repl)
      output = line                             :(rdl)
 done
 end
```

It would not be particularly difficult to handle that case (e.g. ;#131;#58; produces ";#131;:" as well:

```
      dd = "0123456789"
      ccp = "#" (span(dd) $ n ";") $ enc
 +      *?(s = s (lt(n,127) ge(n,32) char(n), char(10) enc))
 +      fence (*ccp | null)
 rdl  line = input                              :f(done)
 repl line "&" *?(s = ) ccp = s                 :s(repl)
      output = replace(line,char(10),"#")       :(rdl)
 done
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version based on [`boost::regex_token_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_token_iterator.html). The program replaces decimal [NCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference)s read from `stdin` by corresponding ASCII characters and prints them to `stdout`.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main()
{
  boost::regex re("&#(1(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-6])|3[2-9]|[4-9][0-9]);"); // 32..126
  const int subs[] = {-1, 1}; // non-match & subexpr
  boost::sregex_token_iterator end;
  std::string line;

  while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    boost::sregex_token_iterator tok(line.begin(), line.end(), re, subs);

    for (bool isncr = false; tok != end; ++tok, isncr = !isncr) {
      if (isncr) { // convert NCR e.g., '&#58;' -> ':'
        const int d = boost::lexical_cast<int>(*tok);
        assert(32 <= d && d < 127);
        std::cout << static_cast<char>(d);
      }
      else
        std::cout << *tok; // output as is
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
}
```